# 'username' and 'password' in inline Javascript event handler in Chrome/Firefox

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, firefox

The variables `username` and `password` do not retain their original value (as defined in the script tag) or are not accessible from the onclick event, however making a function call that outputs the variables does. It seems as though the variables are being redefined inside that scope because they are not undefined even if I don't define them.

It appears to be due to the variables being named `username` and `password`, as shown in the code sample below (`usr` and `passwd` work as expected.)

There is reason to believe this behaviour has been introduced into recent versions of the browser as older Firefox doesn't exhibit it.

Here is a reproducible code sample (tested in Google Chrome 32 / Firefox 26 - however some users are reporting that it does not work for them):

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        var username = "Administrator";
        var password = "AdminPass";

        var usr = "Jordan";
        var passwd = "JordanPass";

        function printCredentials() {
            $("#out").append("username is: " + username + "<br/>");
            $("#out").append("password is: " + password + "<br/>");
            $("#out").append("usr is: " + usr + "<br/>");
            $("#out").append("passwd is: " + passwd + "<br/>");
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <a href="#" onclick="printCredentials()">This works</a><br/>
    <a href="#" onclick="$('#out').append('username is: ' + username + '<br/>'); $('#out').append('password is: ' + password + '<br/>'); $('#out').append('usr is: ' + usr + '<br/>');  $('#out').append('passwd is: ' + passwd + '<br/>');">But this doesn't (properly)</a><br/>
    <div id="out" style="background: yellow"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

[JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Dipak1991/UGkW7/)

Using jQuery is optional, the same happens with regular JS.

Clicking the second link prints out `usr` and `passwd` as expected but `username` and `password` are blank. Curiously, it works as expected (all fields printed) in Internet Explorer.

What is going on here?

Comment: Worked fine for me (FF 21 / Chrome 31)

Comment: Looks like the browser is trying to protect you somehow by hiding the information when the variable name is username or password. I didn't find anything about that. Very interesting.

Comment: does it work without jQuery? can we please get a fiddle? great question for SO btw, kudos.

Comment: ***[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Dipak1991/UGkW7/)*** works fine .Is there any other thing you want to make a note of?

Comment: @Pilot Using that fiddle, clicking the second link, `username` and `password` print out blank. (Chrome 32)

Comment: @JordanTrudgett it works perfectly fine at my end..chrome 32

Comment: no work in chrome33 win for me, even w/o jQuery, so it's a browser thing. new2me!

Comment: And so the plot thickens, then.

Comment: See also http://jibbering.com/faq/names/event_handler.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is actually defined as part of [the HTML5 standard](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/text-level-semantics.html#the-a-element). The `<a>` element is specified to have the following DOM interface:

```
interface HTMLAnchorElement : HTMLElement {
           attribute DOMString target;
           attribute DOMString download;

           attribute DOMString rel;
  readonly attribute DOMTokenList relList;
           attribute DOMString hreflang;
           attribute DOMString type;

           attribute DOMString text;
};
HTMLAnchorElement implements URLUtils;
```

[`URLUtils`](http://url.spec.whatwg.org/#urlutils) is actually [taken from the URL standard](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/infrastructure.html#urlutils), where its behaviour is defined. This is where these properties are actually coming from:

```
[NoInterfaceObject]
interface URLUtils {
  stringifier attribute [EnsureUTF16] DOMString href;
  readonly attribute DOMString origin;

           attribute [EnsureUTF16] DOMString protocol;
           attribute [EnsureUTF16] DOMString username;
           attribute [EnsureUTF16] DOMString password;
           attribute [EnsureUTF16] DOMString host;
           attribute [EnsureUTF16] DOMString hostname;
           attribute [EnsureUTF16] DOMString port;
           attribute [EnsureUTF16] DOMString pathname;
           attribute [EnsureUTF16] DOMString search;
           attribute URLSearchParams? searchParams;
           attribute [EnsureUTF16] DOMString hash;
};
```

These DOM attributes are defined as getters and setters which parse and return the relevant values (on getting) and changes the `href` value upon setting a valid value. For example, `protocol` is simply defined as:

> The protocol attribute must run these steps:
>
> 1. If url is null, return "`:`".
> 2. Return scheme and "`:`" concatenated.

The parts (such as "scheme") are taken from the `href` value, which is parsed as a valid URL.

Note that the way that the interface is described is known as [Web IDL](http://www.w3.org/TR/WebIDL/), which could be considered as a form of pseudocode, though it is actually well specified [under its own specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/WebIDL/).

Because it is a new standard, it has only been implemented very recently (which might explain why this issue was not relevant earlier) -- this was only implemented by Firefox in version 26.

Comment: This was the kind of answer I was looking for when I started the bounty; a reference to the standard on which this behaviour is based. I think it answers the question in the most canonical fashion and so I have marked it as the answer to this question. Bonus points for investigating why this issue has come up recently.

Comment: @Qantas out of curiosity, I would like to know, was it possible for you to get this answer without my answer? I mean before I answer, this question has been here for 4 days and yet no ones can answer it. Then you just posted answer after I posted it. Since author already accepted your answer, it doesn't matter now but I'm just curios :)

Comment: @Rezigned: that's an interesting question -- not to say your answer isn't great too, you got a +1 from me. I don't usually look at the bounties, but I found this question here at the time that your answer was only a guess, and set out to find an official answer. I first managed to find it through a Google search for ["username" anchor element](http://google.com/#q="username"+anchor+element), which managed to get me to the [MDN's article on it](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/HTMLAnchorElement). From there, I managed to search up the relevant specifications and give my answer.

Answer (score 5):

Here's a break down why you can't see `username` and `password` attribute

First of all, `<a>` tag is capable of parsing the `url` in `href` attribute and make the parsed values into its own property.

**NOTE** URL syntax `<protocol>://<user>:<password>@<host>:<port>/<url-path>`

```
var a = document.createElement('a');
a.setAttribute('href', 'http://john:doe@google.com');

// Do you get the idea now?
a.username // prints "john"
a.password // prints "doe"
```

That's it, your inline `onclick` is being executed against `a`'s scope which already has both `username` and `password` property defined (with "" values)

```
+----------------+
| window.username|  <-- your "Administrator"
|                |
| +------------+ |
| | a.username | |  <-- empty by default ""
| +------------+ |
+----------------+
```

**EDIT**: In case you would like to see the Chrome's source code where it defines username/password interface & implementation

Interface: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/codesearch#chromium/src/third_party/WebKit/Source/core/dom/DOMURLUtils.h&l=47&rcl=1391416355

Implementation: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/codesearch#chromium/src/third_party/WebKit/Source/core/dom/DOMURLUtils.cpp&l=48&rcl=1391416355

**Explanation:** When I answer this question I assumed that everyone already knows about `this` keyword in `onclick` event and `Scope` in javascript, but looks like it's not clear enough (my bad).

This line `"is being executed against <a>'s scope"` means that,

```
onclick="alert(username)" === onclick="alert(this.username)"
```

That is, you can think of anything in `onclick` is an anonymous function which is bound to `<a>` tag so

```
onclick = function() {
    log(this);     // 1. bound to `<a>` not `window`
    log(username); // 2. implies `this.username` unless you explicitly declare 'var username`
}
```

How Javascript scope works is, if it can't find that variable (`username`) in local scope, it will look at the outer scope for it `window.username`.

Hope that should make it more clearer.

Comment: (I wasn't the one who downvoted.) This sounds correct, but the same thing happens with a `div` tag? And it works in some browsers but not others...

Comment: that's the answer, that "this" is taken and bound to something beside window, as though a WITH command is in-play. if you change <a to <b, it seems to work as expected.

Comment: @Whymarrh I just tested it with a div tag - it correctly prints out the contents of the username and password variables. I believe that this is the correct explanation.

Comment: this should make it clear what's going on: <a href="#" onclick="alert(this.outerHTML)">whoami</a>

Comment: actually, this should make it clearer: <b onclick="alert(outerHTML)">whoami</b> ... I didn't realize that onclick works like with(this){ code }, but this example proves that once and for all.

Comment: @dandavis I've added more explanation about javascript scope, hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for your investigation! Does this explain why the behaviour is exhibited in some browsers and not others? (Specifically some users reporting their Chrome did not 'hide' `username` and `password`?)

+1 for references to relevant source code and explanation of scope.

Comment: @JordanTrudgett If they're using Chrome I'm quite sure that the result will be the same (unless he misunderstood the result).

Answer (score 1):

While I'm not 100% sure on the exact reason behind it, the issue lies with your variable names 'username' and 'password'.

If you changed the variable names it all works fine.

> In addition to the above reserved words, you'd better avoid the following identifiers as names of JavaScript variables. These are predefined names of implementation-dependent JavaScript objects, methods, or properties (and, arguably, some should have been reserved words): ...password...
>   http://www.javascripter.net/faq/reserved.htm

Comment: I read the same thing, but he's still able to use those variable names in the rest of the code.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I agree it has to do with the variable names - the question is why ;) Good link. I tried searching for such a list before. It specifies `password` but not `username`, strangely.

Comment: The article does note that 'These are predefined names of implementation-dependent...' so in the particular implementation that Chrome32/FF16 it may use 'username' too.

As for why it works in the function, I'm not qualified to answer that but I would have to guess it has something to do with scope.

Comment: @user109486: it has the same scope as the other variables which do work. this probably needs a bounty to keep from getting lost, it's a real puzzle!

Comment: …and here's the reason why they are unsafe: http://jibbering.com/faq/names/event_handler.html

Answer (score 0):

Here is my fiddle and it works: http://jsfiddle.net/kP2EU/2/

Instead of allowing var username and var password, I assigned username and password as properties of the window object `window.username` and `window.password` and then used those references in the anchor tag's onClick event. That worked fine in both scenarios.

**JS**:

```
 window.username = "Administrator";
 window.password = "AdminPass";

 var usr = "Jordan";
 var passwd = "JordanPass";

 function printCredentials() {
     $("#out").append("username is: " + window.username + "<br/>");
     $("#out").append("password is: " + window.password + "<br/>");
     $("#out").append("usr is: " + usr + "<br/>");
     $("#out").append("passwd is: " + passwd + "<br/>");
 }
```

**HTML**:

```
<a href="#" onclick="printCredentials()">This works</a>
<br/> <a href="#" onclick="$('#out').append('username is: ' + window.username + '<br/>'); $('#out').append('password is: ' + window.password + '<br/>'); $('#out').append('usr is: ' + usr + '<br/>');  $('#out').append('passwd is: ' + passwd + '<br/>');">But this doesn't (properly)</a>
<br/>
<div id="out" style="background: yellow"></div>
```

I still can't find any reference to anything in the chrome environment that says you can't use variable names username and password in an anchor tag's onClick event.

**Update**: http://jsfiddle.net/kP2EU/3/
instead of assigning to `window.username` and `window.password` it still uses `var username` and `var password` but the anchor tags refers to `window.username` and `window.password`

**Update 2**:
I was using the developer tools in chrome and was able to get back in to the onClick event stack and found that username and password are I guess attributes of the anchor tag by chrome's definition.  I'm working on trying to figure out where it is defined to provide a link or more information here.

Comment: I understand, was just trying to show that the "variable" still exists within the scope of the anchor tag onclick, but not as a bare word. I'm interested myself where this is documented among the Chrome javascript implementation.

Comment: I was digging around in the fiddle using developer tools, and created a function to pass the username and password variables too.  I was able to go back to the onClick event scope and discovered as part of the "a" block that username and password are I guess attributes of the anchor tag as defined by chrome.